# How can I map a few tables together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to figure out how to create a small database given the fields in the picture below.

[image]

I haven’t even see this data yet, but I’m told I will get something like wat you see in the image.  I’m wondering how to choose a unique ID for each table.  I think the ID will be the orange field, but in case one of the tables don’t actually have this kind of ID, how can I create a unique ID from the data sets?  Maybe something like the left 5 characters of two fields concatenated together.  I’m just thinking out loud here.  Also, how can I map these tables together?  Will I need to create another table with all the IDs and map it that way?  I’m trying to figure out the best practice here.
Thanks!

The data sets will look something like this (below).

[image]

The two orange fields (IDs) must be linked together.  There really isn't a universal ID common to all data sets, so the only way to do this is create a mapping table, based on the logic of the business hierarchy, right.  That's the only way to do it.

Comment: It depends on what you plan to do with the data.  Data warehouse or other reporting?  Are you upgrading an application and the data will now reside in a new database?  You also should get, if possible, a short description of each data column.

Comment: I don't see the relation unless its somehow related level3. If you have to map the data you will need business rules that could take some time and be prone to error if you rely solely on blind analysis. Wherever the data originated there is 'mapping' data. I recommend you try very hard to get it.